# What is exactly an overlong form/encoding?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, sequences, codepoint

Reading the [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), I've been wondering about the term **overlong**. This term is used various times but the article doesn't provide a definition or reference for its meaning.

I would like to know if someone can explain the term and its purpose.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an encoding of a code point which takes more code units than it needs to.

For example, U+0020 is represented in UTF-8 by the single byte `0x20`. If you decode the two bytes `0xc0 0xa0` in the normal fashion, you'll still end up back at U+0020, but that's an invalid representation.

The [Unicode Corrigendum #1](http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum1.html) has more information, particularly around table 3.1B.

Answer (score 7):

UTF-8 theoretically allows for different representations of characters that also have a shorter one. For example, you could encode an ASCII character in two bytes by setting the MSBs to zero. The UTF-8 specification explicitly forbids this.